# Class 'AMQPConnection' not found. AMQP and PHP api version conflict

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp, pecl

After one of PHP updates (ubuntu) I got an error **Class 'AMQPConnection' not found** in my application.
I reinstalled latest stable version (1.7.1) of **amqp** via **pecl**

```
sudo pecl uninstall amqp

sudo pecl install amqp
```

It asks me:

> downloading amqp-1.7.1.tgz ...
>
> Starting to download amqp-1.7.1.tgz (79,905 bytes)
>
> ..................done: 79,905 bytes
>
> 18 source files, building
>
> running: phpize
>
> Configuring for:
>
> PHP Api Version:         20121113
>
> Zend Module Api No:      20121212
>
> Zend Extension Api No:   220121212
>
> Set the path to librabbitmq install prefix [autodetect] :

When I choose one of the variants - builds fails, error always like

> configure: error: Please reinstall the librabbitmq distribution itself or (re)install librabbitmq development package if it available in your system
>   ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/amqp/configure --with-librabbitmq-dir=20121113' failed

If I choose **autodetect**, installation proccessed successfully.
Then I add **extension=amqp.so** into **php.ini** and get an error

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/amqp.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/amqp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

I found **amqp.so** via

```
locate amqp.so
```

It display

> /usr/lib/php5/20121212/amqp.so

Then I change **extension=amqp.so** to the full path **/usr/lib/php5/20121212/amqp.so**

And I get very interesting error

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: amqp: Unable to initialize module
>   Module compiled with module API=20121212
>   PHP    compiled with module API=20131226
>   These options need to match
>    in Unknown on line 0

As I understand, PHP compiled with version newest than Amqp.
But it is the latest amqp library version.
Pecl shows:

> Package Stable/(Latest) Local
>
> amqp    1.7.1 (stable)  1.7.1 Communicate with any AMQP compliant server

PHP version is 5.6.4

> PHP 5.6.4-4ubuntu6 (cli) (built: Apr 17 2015 15:47:51)
>
> Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
>
> Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend
>
> Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.2.6, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans

Comment: Do you need to use the PECL package? Maybe you could try this instead: [php amqp lib](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib)

Comment: Hi, php-amqp contributor here. Can you provide what ubuntu version do you use? From what you posted you compiled php-amqp against php-5.5 (API 20121212) but you use php-5.6 (API 20131226). It seems to be that you have multiple php installed and pecl picked 5.5 rather then 5.6.

Comment: @pinepain, Hi, I use Linux Mint 17.03.



**Linux ubuntu-69 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux**

Comment: @pinepain, Can you advice plz, how can I find or delete 5.5 version? I can't find anything about it, php -v says that current version is 5.6 ...

Comment: @KaloyanDoichinov, I use vendor packages that depends on amqp extension.

Comment: @Fruty, you can try to find everything related to php e.g. `whereis php` or even look into pecl config what's in use - `pecl config-show | grep php` or even `sudo pecl config-show | grep php` (just in case the output will differ somehow).

Comment: @pinepain, whereis php shows only php with 5.6. But pecl config params says, that it's really looks like, that it think about 5.5 version. 


  `PHP extension directory        ext_dir          /usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs` and 
`PEAR Installer download        download_dir     /build/php5-DgntdS/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/pear-build-download`

Comment: You can simply alter pecl config to point to proper php version and dirs. Or remove 5.5 completely (though, be carefully if you decide to remove, some of your apps/scripts may depend on it). You may search for cases like yours, it looks like a general problem not specific to php-amqp or any other php extension.